# What is a 'prayer mission'?

Tags: meaning, culture

It's actually a religious or cultural question but still I don't know what it is so I decided to post it here. I searched it online including on Wikipedia but I couldn't find a straight answer to it probably because I'm not really familiar with Christianity. In Family Guy, the grandpa as the answer to the question, "where's grandma?" says, *"she's on her prayer mission in Las Vegas."*

Is it something all people can do? And what do they do exactly on this mission?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, a "mission" in the Christian faith is a trip one takes to help others and/or spread the gospel. An example would be a group of Christians from a church going to Haiti to help build or repair a school or orphanage.

The quote from Family Guy was making a joke about Grandma going to Las Vegas on a mission, not to help someone else, but to gamble. She's specifically on a "prayer mission" to pray she wins.

Comment: +1 Thank you... so _prayer_ before mission was just used humorously and _prayer mission_ doesn't really exist but _missions_ really exist in Christianity. Right?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: @Yuri **Not** correct! _Prayer mission_ is a genuine term for a genuine phenomenon. Among adherents of many denominations of Christianity, a _prayer mission_ is a specific event. It can mean travelling in a group to pray together in support of a person or event. See [**this link**](http://www.livinghopevt.com/#/prayer/prayer-mission) or [**this one.**](http://www.eauk.org/idea/reverse-missionaries-how-the-migrant-church-is-shaping-european-christianity.cfm)

Comment: @Yuri Follow the links I provided. In a _prayer mission,_ a group or individual goes somewhere and prays to some deity about something.

Comment: @P. E. Dant I did and that was interesting thumbs-up